# Process-wide named property on osx and or linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, posix

I have a complex project with a lot of dlls (some of them are plug-ins i.e. they cannot share linker symbol names freely) and I look for an ability to put some information which other dlls can get safely. If to assume that setenv function is thread-safe I would be totally happy.

So What I look for is something like

```
int val = get_or_create_process_wide_property("my_prop", 10);
if (val == 10) {   //property just was created
}
else {   //property was set by somebody else and we can use it
}
```

shm_open except it's a little bit overhead requires shm_unlink, which I never can be sure is called because a process can crash.

Comment: You honestly might want to just use a temporary file for a case like this maybe

Comment: This gives system-wide properties. I.e. the file will live until OS reboot. what is ok, but not perfect, if I create a file my_file.<pid>.tmp in /tmp and my process crashed then the file will stay there forever...

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are distinct languages.  For example, c++ allows overloading of functions and many compilers use name mangling to differentiate from the overloads.  Name mangling may not be compatible with .so or .dlls.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: If you have assembly/low-level knowledge you can try and reserve a block of memory for whatever data you need and access it directly? Unsure how you'd be able to share the memory address between DLL's though unless you can somehow guarantee you can get that block at for example 0xA134

Comment: Yes, I think about the block, however I also don't know how to get "safe" address to mmap for example. Nowadays with all these Load Address Randomization features it's too complex

Comment: Anything wrong with `getenv` and `setenv`?

Comment: they are not thread safe, if they are - they would be just beyond the perfection

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing / vague. First, DLL is a Windows term. As the OS's you've listed are UNIX-based, the term you want is probably "library".

Next, you have a bunch of libraries. As you're implementing a custom way of setting properties, I presume you have control over how the code that is built into those various libraries obtain their data.

You've said the values need to be available within a single process. Why not just create a class to manage all this, some sort of setting registry? I'm not sure why this is hard.

Comment: Okay, assume there is a DAW. (Digital Audio Workstation, like Ableton for example) I have 2 plug-ins. I need to connect them somehow. They are in the same process, they cannot see each other though. And they should not have "excessive" public symbols which they export.

Comment: Could one of your plugins implement a socket-based key/value server? All your plugins could attach to that. You'd have to implement a scheme to know what port number to use, although that could be related to the PID, or a constant if this collection of plugins is guaranteed to be a singleton on the machine. There would be a variety of ways to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, a socket is a good idea. Not perfect as well though because it's still process-externally visible, while it has no any reason to be.

Comment: You're running in some sort of container environment where plugins aren't encouraged to talk to each other. If plugins aren't really allowed to talk to each other, they may as well be in different processes. You could cheat, though. You could store somewhere the address of the registry. After all, if it's C++, you can set pointers to any arbitrary location, right? Do you have control over how all these plugins launch in the first place?